# netty 3.6.0 runtime error with LineBasedFrameDecoder

Tags: netty

Upgraded to netty 3.6.0. Tried to replace

DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder with LineBasedFrameDecoder as suggested with release on the website. Got the following runtime error. Any suggestions. ??

Code used.

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
pipeline.addLast("framer", new LineBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Runtime Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LineBasedFrameDecoder.extractFrame(Lorg/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer;II)Lorg/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer;
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LineBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LineBasedFrameDecoder.java:95)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:422)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:84)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:471)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:332)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: This can be possible if both 3.6.0 and some elder version of Netty are in classpath. Since this method was added to this class only in 3.6.0 and there is no this method in older version of FrameDecoder class.

Comment: Agreed - where did you get the netty `.jar` you are using? Looking at the current 3.6.0 source ... this shouldn't happen. And the method is there in the 3.6.0-Final.jar in maven central.

Comment: I did check my classpath for older versions of netty before i posted the problem. Let me recheck. Thanks

Comment: yes it was a classpath problem. I had an older version of the library in a dependency project. Thanks